# Custom exception thrown from enum is not caught in @ExceptionalHandler

Tags: java, spring-boot, enums

Question: How to catch the custom exception in @ExceptionalHandler method.

I have a request body in the controller which takes a enum value. I have written a enum

```
   public enum Car{
    
    TOYOTA;
    
    @JsonCreator
    public static Car fromValue(String value) throws Exception{
    
    if(value !=null){
     for(Car enumvalue: Car.class.getEnumConstants()){
        if(enumValue.name().toLowerCase().equals(value.toLowerCase())){
        return enumValue;
        }
     }
    
    }
    
    throw new MyCustomException("Incorrect enum value");
    }
    }
```

Below is the exceptional handler method i have written in controller

```
@ExceptionHandler(MyCustomException.class)
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleEnum(MyCustomException e){
//code to send the response back with custom message
}
```

Exceptional Handler method works if I handle ValueInstantiationException instead of MyCustomException

Logs:
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.demo.model.Domain`, problem: Incorrect enum Value; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.ValueInstantiationException:

Comment: I think the code in ```if(value !=null){``` throws ```ValueInstantiationException```. You can wrap the ```if``` block in try catch and then throw the custom exception through the catch block

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: How to catch the custom exception in @ExceptionalHandler method.

Comment: You are catching it, however it's caught before it reaches any @ExceptionHandler, and wrapped into ValueInstantiationException. If you add ExcetionHandler for ValueInstantiationException, you probably will find your MyCustomException in a `cause` property of ValueInstantiationException

Comment: That is correct. I just debugged the code now and I was able to find the MyCustomException in the cause property. Thanks.